# how to integrate a GUI dll into another application (like windows or wpf application)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, dll, console-application

I am new to dll related concepts.
I have created a dll which imports data.
Now this dll actually was a console application and it can browse file using openfiledialog and even shows messages using messagebox.
And this message box and openfiledialog was created dynamically..
The application in itself works very fine..
Now I am required to create a dll of it and integrate to another application now this application can be windows or even wpf..

Is it possible to do so?
Because when I am integrating the dll to windows form I am actually getting IO exception unhandled error..

Yes some of you may suggest like executing the exe in other application which works fine but can dll too be created?

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer add new project. Select class library. Put your code there, create some public methods so other classes (UI) can access the logic/operations there. Thus it should be independent from the view/controller and if the code works independently it should work with wpf or winforms or whatever on top of it.